# 'emit' Vs 'return' in Qt - Similarities and Differences

Tags: qt, return, emit

I just came across 'emit' in Qt programming. I would like to know more about its function. Does it work like 'return' by any chance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: emit and return works different.

Answer (score 0):

No emit and return are not same. object can emit signal on it's state change. Interested objects can register their slot to this signal through connect call. All registered slots will get called on signal emit. you need to go through Qt's signal slot https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html to understand emit.